# Как PHPUnit заставить видеть данные в базе данных?

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

Всем привет, куча подобных вопросов. Но мой случай видать особенный тк все они не помогли.
Есть сущность (PersonalArea) которая в себе имеет еще три сущности (Broker, SbCheckStatus, StatusVip) (связь ManyToOne)
Перед тем как сохранить эту сущность создаю все три сущности, сохраняю в БД и потом пытаюсь сохранить Главную сущность, на что PHPUnit ругается, мол не существуют в БД эти три сущности (хотя они там есть + client->disableReboot() есть)
Вот исходники для понятности

```
namespace App\Tests;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

/**
 * Class BaseTest
 * @package App\Tests
 */
class BaseTest extends WebTestCase
{
    /** @var EntityManager */
    protected $em;

    public function __construct($name = null, array $data = [], $dataName = '')
    {
        parent::__construct($name, $data, $dataName);

        self::bootKernel();
        $this->em = parent::$container->get('doctrine')->getManager();
    }

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        //$this->em->beginTransaction();
    }

    protected function tearDown(): void
    {
        // doing this is recommended to avoid memory leaks
        //$this->em->rollback();
        $this->em->close();
        $this->em = null;
        parent::tearDown();
    }
}
```

-

```
namespace App\Tests\Functional;

use App\Tests\BaseTest;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\KernelBrowser;

/**
 * Class BaseFunctionalTest
 * @package App\Tests\Functional
 */
class BaseFunctionalTest extends BaseTest
{
    /** @var KernelBrowser */
    protected $client;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->client = static::createClient(['environment' => 'test']);
        $this->client->disableReboot();
    }

    protected function tearDown(): void
    {
        $this->client = null;
        parent::tearDown();
    }
}
```

-

```
<?php

namespace App\Tests\Functional;

use App\Entity\Broker;
use App\Entity\PersonalArea;
use App\Entity\SbCheckStatus;
use App\Entity\StatusVip;
use App\Helper\DataGenerator\Entity\Broker as BrokerDataGenerator;
use App\Helper\DataGenerator\Entity\PersonalArea as PersonalAreaDataGenerator;
use App\Helper\DataGenerator\Entity\SbCheckStatus as SbCheckStatusDataGenerator;
use App\Helper\DataGenerator\Entity\StatusVip as StatusVipDataGenerator;
use App\Repository\BrokerRepository;
use App\Repository\personalAreaRepository;
use App\Repository\SbCheckStatusRepository;
use App\Repository\StatusVipRepository;
use App\Service\BrokerService;
use App\Service\SbCheckStatusService;
use App\Service\StatusVipService;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

/**
 * Class PersonalAreaControllerTest
 * @package App\Tests\Functional
 */
final class PersonalAreaControllerTest extends BaseFunctionalTest
{
    /** @var array Актуальные данные личного кабинета (для добавления) */
    private static $personalAreaActualData = [];

    /** @var array Новые данные личного кабинета (для обновления) */
    private static $personalAreaNewData = [];

    /** @var BrokerRepository $brokerRepository */
    private $brokerRepository;

    /** @var PersonalAreaRepository $personalAreaRepository */
    private $personalAreaRepository;

    /** @var SbCheckStatusRepository $sbCheckStatusRepository */
    private $sbCheckStatusRepository;

    /** @var StatusVipRepository $statusVipRepository */
    private $statusVipRepository;

    public function __construct($name = null, array $data = [], $dataName = '')
    {
        parent::__construct($name, $data, $dataName);

        $brokerService = parent::$container->get(BrokerService::class);
        $brokerService->createBroker(BrokerDataGenerator::generate());
        $this->brokerRepository = $this->em->getRepository(Broker::class);
        $broker = $this->brokerRepository->getLastAddedBroker();

        $sbCheckStatusService = parent::$container->get(SbCheckStatusService::class);
        $sbCheckStatusService->createSbCheckStatus(SbCheckStatusDataGenerator::generate());
        $this->sbCheckStatusRepository = $this->em->getRepository(SbCheckStatus::class);
        $sbCheckStatus = $this->sbCheckStatusRepository->getLastAddedSbCheckStatus();

        $statusVipService = parent::$container->get(StatusVipService::class);
        $statusVipService->createStatusVip(StatusVipDataGenerator::generate());
        $this->statusVipRepository = $this->em->getRepository(StatusVip::class);
        $statusVip = $this->statusVipRepository->getLastAddedStatusVip();

        self::$personalAreaActualData = PersonalAreaDataGenerator::generate(
            $broker->getId(),
            $sbCheckStatus->getId(),
            $statusVip->getId()
        );
        self::$personalAreaNewData = PersonalAreaDataGenerator::generate(
            $broker->getId(),
            $sbCheckStatus->getId(),
            $statusVip->getId()
        );
    }

    public function testAPI(): void
    {
        $this->addAction();
        $this->getAction();
        $this->updateAction();
        $this->listAction();
        $this->deleteAction();
    }

    /**
     * Тестирование маршрута добавления личного кабинета
     * [POST] /api/personal_area/
     */
    private function addAction(): void
    {
        $this->client->request(
            Request::METHOD_POST,
            '/api/personal_area/',
            [],
            [],
            ['CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'],
            json_encode(self::$personalAreaActualData)
        );

        $this->assertEquals(Response::HTTP_CREATED, $this->client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
    }

    /**
     * Тестирование маршрута получения личного кабинета
     * [GET] /api/personal_area/{id}
     */
    private function getAction(): void
    {
        $personalArea = $this->personalAreaRepository->getLastAddedPersonalArea();

        $this->client->request(Request::METHOD_GET, sprintf('/api/personal_area/%d', $personalArea->getId()));
        $this->assertEquals(Response::HTTP_OK, $this->client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());

        $expectedPersonalArea = [
            'id' => $personalArea->getId(),
            'name' => self::$personalAreaActualData['name'],
            'sum_for_check_status' => self::$personalAreaActualData['sum_for_check_status'],
        ];
        $actualPersonalArea = json_decode($this->client->getResponse()->getContent(), true);
        $this->assertEquals($expectedPersonalArea, $actualPersonalArea);
    }

    /**
     * Тестирование маршрута обновления личного кабинета
     * [PUT] /api/personal_area/{id}
     */
    private function updateAction(): void
    {
        $personalArea = $this->personalAreaRepository->getLastAddedPersonalArea();
        $this->assertInstanceOf(PersonalArea::class, $personalArea);

        $this->client->request(
            Request::METHOD_PUT,
            sprintf('/api/personal_area/%d', $personalArea->getId()),
            [],
            [],
            ['CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'],
            json_encode(self::$personalAreaNewData)
        );
        $this->assertEquals(Response::HTTP_OK, $this->client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
        self::$personalAreaActualData = self::$personalAreaNewData;
    }

    /**
     * Тестирование маршрута получения списка личных кабинетов
     * [GET] /api/personal_area/
     */
    private function listAction(): void
    {
        $personalArea = $this->personalAreaRepository->getLastAddedPersonalArea();

        $this->client->request(Request::METHOD_GET, '/api/personal_area/');
        $this->assertEquals(Response::HTTP_OK, $this->client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());

        $expectedPersonalAreaList = [
            [
                'id' => $personalArea->getId(),
                'name' => self::$personalAreaActualData['name'],
                'sum_for_check_status' => self::$personalAreaActualData['sum_for_check_status'],
            ],
        ];
        $actualPersonalAreaList = json_decode($this->client->getResponse()->getContent(), true);
        $this->assertEquals($expectedPersonalAreaList, $actualPersonalAreaList);
    }

    /**
     * Тестирование маршрута удаления личного кабинета
     * [DELETE] /api/personal_area/{id}
     */
    public function deleteAction(): void
    {
        $personalArea = $this->personalAreaRepository->getLastAddedPersonalArea();

        $this->client->request(Request::METHOD_DELETE, sprintf('/api/personal_area/%d', $personalArea->getId()));
        $this->assertEquals(Response::HTTP_NO_CONTENT, $this->client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());

        $this->client->request(Request::METHOD_GET, sprintf('/api/personal_area/%d', $personalArea->getId()));
        $this->assertEquals(Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND, $this->client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
    }

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->brokerRepository = $this->em->getRepository(Broker::class);
        $this->personalAreaRepository = $this->em->getRepository(PersonalArea::class);
        $this->sbCheckStatusRepository = $this->em->getRepository(SbCheckStatus::class);
        $this->statusVipRepository = $this->em->getRepository(StatusVip::class);
    }

    protected function tearDown(): void
    {
        $this->brokerRepository = null;
        $this->personalAreaRepository = null;
        $this->sbCheckStatusRepository = null;
        $this->statusVipRepository = null;
        parent::tearDown();
    }
}
```

-

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Assert as CustomAssert;
use DateTime;
use DateTimeInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Объект личного кабинета
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PersonalAreaRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(options={"comment":"Личный кабинет"})
 */
class PersonalArea
{
    public const ACTIVE = 'active';
    public const NOT_ACTIVE = 'not_active';
    public const ACTIVE_LIST = [
        self::ACTIVE => self::ACTIVE,
        self::NOT_ACTIVE => self::NOT_ACTIVE,
    ];

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"unsigned"=true})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * Фамилия
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, options={"comment":"Фамилия"})
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Length(max=255, maxMessage="Максимальное число вводимых символов не должна превышать 255.")
     * @Assert\Regex(
     *     pattern="/^[\w\d_-]+$/i",
     *     message="В фамилии допустимы только латинские буквы, цыфры, дефис и знак подчеркивания."
     * )
     */
    private $surname;

    /**
     * Имя
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, options={"comment":"Имя"})
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Length(max=255, maxMessage="Максимальное число вводимых символов не должна превышать 255.")
     * @Assert\Regex(
     *     pattern="/^[\w\d_-]+$/i",
     *     message="В имени допустимы только латинские буквы, цыфры, дефис и знак подчеркивания."
     * )
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * Отчество
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, options={"comment":"Отчество"})
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Length(max=255, maxMessage="Максимальное число вводимых символов не должна превышать 255.")
     * @Assert\Regex(
     *     pattern="/^[\w\d_-]+$/i",
     *     message="В отчестве допустимы только латинские буквы, цыфры, дефис и знак подчеркивания."
     * )
     */
    private $middleName;

    /**
     * Email
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true, options={"comment":"Email"})
     * @Assert\Email(message="Email ""{{ value }}"" не является валидным.")
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * Телефон
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true, options={"comment":"Телефон"})
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Regex(
     *     pattern="/^[+]\d{1,4}\d{10}$/i",
     *     message="Номер телефона должен быть в формате +79991112233 где код страны может быть от 1 до 4 цыфр."
     * )
     */
    private $phone;

    /**
     * Дата дня рождения в формате "Y-m-d"
     * @var DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(type="date", options={"comment":"Дата дня рождения"})
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $birthday;

    /**
     * Дата создания записи
     * @var DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=false, options={"comment":"Дата создания записи"})
     * @ORM\Version
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * Дата последнего обновления записи
     * @var DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=false, options={"comment":"Дата последнего обновления записи"})
     * @ORM\Version
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(
     *     name="usdt_tether",
     *     type="string",
     *     length=255,
     *     options={"comment":"Tether — криптовалютный токен, выпущенный компанией Tether Limited"}
     * )
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Length(max=255, maxMessage="Максимальное число вводимых символов не должна превышать 255.")
     * @Assert\Regex(
     *     pattern="/^[\w\d]+$/i",
     *     message="В токене допустимы только латинские буквы и цыфры."
     * )
     */
    private $usdtTether;

    /**
     * Флаг указывающий активен ли кабинет
     * @var string|int
     * @ORM\Column(
     *     length=16,
     *     columnDefinition="ENUM('active', 'not_active')",
     *     options={"comment":"Флаг указывающий активен ли кабинет. ENUM('active', 'not_active')"}
     * )
     * @Assert\Choice(choices={"active", "not-active", 1, 2}, message="Выбирите валидное значение.")
     */
    private $active;

    /**
     * Брокер
     * @var Broker
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Broker")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="broker_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     * @CustomAssert\Constraint\BrokerConstraint()
     */
    private $broker;

    /**
     * Объект статуса проверки СБ
     * @var SbCheckStatus
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SbCheckStatus")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="sb_check_status_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     * @CustomAssert\Constraint\SbCheckStatusConstraint()
     */
    private $sbCheckStatus;

    /**
     * Объект VIP статуса
     * @var StatusVip
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="StatusVip")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="status_vip_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     * @CustomAssert\Constraint\StatusVipConstraint()
     */
    private $statusVip;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $currentTimestamp = new DateTime();
        $this->setCreatedAt($currentTimestamp);
        $this->setUpdatedAt($currentTimestamp);
    }

    /**
     * @return int|null
     */
    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getSurname(): ?string
    {
        return $this->surname;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $surname
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setSurname(string $surname): self
    {
        $this->surname = $surname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getMiddleName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->middleName;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $middleName
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setMiddleName(string $middleName): self
    {
        $this->middleName = $middleName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $email
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getPhone(): ?string
    {
        return $this->phone;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $phone
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setPhone(string $phone): self
    {
        $this->phone = $phone;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return DateTimeInterface|null
     */
    public function getBirthday(): ?DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->birthday;
    }

    /**
     * @param DateTimeInterface $birthday
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setBirthday(DateTimeInterface $birthday): self
    {
        $this->birthday = $birthday;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return DateTimeInterface|null
     */
    public function getCreatedAt(): ?DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * @param DateTimeInterface $createdAt
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setCreatedAt(DateTimeInterface $createdAt): self
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return DateTimeInterface|null
     */
    public function getUpdatedAt(): ?DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    /**
     * @param DateTimeInterface $updatedAt
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setUpdatedAt(DateTimeInterface $updatedAt): self
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getUsdtTether(): ?string
    {
        return $this->usdtTether;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $usdtTether
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setUsdtTether(string $usdtTether): self
    {
        $this->usdtTether = $usdtTether;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Broker|null
     */
    public function getBroker(): ?Broker
    {
        return $this->broker;
    }

    /**
     * @param Broker $broker
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setBroker(Broker $broker): self
    {
        $this->broker = $broker;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getActive(): ?string
    {
        return $this->active;
    }

    /**
     * @param int|string $active Флаг активности (int 1 -> Активный, int 2 -> Не активный)
     *                           (также можно использовать "active", "not_active")
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setActive($active): self
    {
        $this->active = $active;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return SbCheckStatus|null
     */
    public function getSbCheckStatus(): ?SbCheckStatus
    {
        return $this->sbCheckStatus;
    }

    /**
     * @param SbCheckStatus $sbCheckStatus
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setSbCheckStatus(SbCheckStatus $sbCheckStatus): self
    {
        $this->sbCheckStatus = $sbCheckStatus;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return StatusVip|null
     */
    public function getStatusVip(): ?StatusVip
    {
        return $this->statusVip;
    }

    /**
     * @param StatusVip $statusVip
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setStatusVip(StatusVip $statusVip): self
    {
        $this->statusVip = $statusVip;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

-

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Broker;
use App\Entity\PersonalArea;
use App\Entity\SbCheckStatus;
use App\Entity\StatusVip;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

/**
 * Class PersonalAreaType
 * @package App\Form
 */
class PersonalAreaType extends BaseType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilder|FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array                            $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('surname', TextType::class, [
                'invalid_message' => 'Фамилия должна быть строкового типа.',
            ])
            ->add('name', TextType::class, [
                'invalid_message' => 'Имя должно быть строкового типа.',
            ])
            ->add('middle_name', TextType::class, [
                'invalid_message' => 'Отчество должно быть строкового типа.',
            ])
            ->add('email', EmailType::class, [
                'invalid_message' => 'Email должен быть строкового типа.',
            ])
            ->add('phone', TextType::class, [
                'invalid_message' => 'Телефон должен быть строкового типа в фомате "+79001112233".',
            ])
            ->add('birthday', DateType::class, [
                'invalid_message' => 'Дата дня рождения должна быть строкового типа в фомате "Y-m-d".',
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
                'input' => 'datetime',
            ])
            ->add('usdt_tether', TextType::class, [
                'invalid_message' => 'Tether-токен должен быть строкового типа.',
            ])
            ->add('active', TextType::class, [
                'invalid_message' => 'Флаг активности должен быть строкового типа.',
            ])
            ->add('broker', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Broker::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'invalid_message' => 'Брокер с ID:{{ value }} не найден.',
            ])
            ->add('sb_check_status', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => SbCheckStatus::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'invalid_message' => 'Статус проверки СБ с ID:{{ value }} не найден.',
            ])
            ->add('status_vip', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => StatusVip::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'invalid_message' => 'Указанный VIP-статус с ID:{{ value }} не найден.',
            ]);
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        parent::configureOptions($resolver);
        $resolver->setDefaults(['data_class' => PersonalArea::class]);
    }

    /**
     * @param PersonalArea     $personalArea
     * @param AbstractPlatform $platform
     * @return PersonalArea|int
     */
    public function convertToDatabaseValue($personalArea, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return $personalArea instanceof PersonalArea
            ? $personalArea->getId()
            : $personalArea;
    }
}
```

-

````
- Добавить новый личный кабинет:
    ```
    curl -X POST http://localhost/api/personal_area/ -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
        "surname": "Surname",
        "name": "Name",
        "middle_name": "Middle_name",
        "email": "email@mail.ru",
        "phone": "+790136341481",
        "birthday": "1992-11-11",
        "usdt_tether": "usdt_tether",
        "active": "active",
        "broker": 1,
        "sb_check_status": 1,
        "status_vip": 1
    }'
    ```
````

Comment: Ребят очень надеюсь на Вашу помощь, целый день уже с этим вожусь. Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Всех прошу прощения, вчера до поздна сидел и уже мозг не соображал. Сегодня на свежую голову нашел ошибку за 5 минут. Ошибка была в той части которую я не показал, а именно:

```
self::$personalAreaActualData = PersonalAreaDataGenerator::generate(
    $broker->getId(),
    $sbCheckStatus->getId(),
    $statusVip->getId()
);
self::$personalAreaNewData = PersonalAreaDataGenerator::generate(
    $broker->getId(),
    $sbCheckStatus->getId(),
    $statusVip->getId()
);
```

И собственно в комменте ниже написал где именно

```
<?php

namespace App\Helper\DataGenerator\Entity;

use App\Helper\DataGenerator\BaseDataGenerator;

/**
 * Class PersonalArea
 * @package App\Helper\DataGenerator\Entity
 */
class PersonalArea extends BaseDataGenerator
{
    /**
     * Сгенерировать данные для сущности личного кабинета
     * @param int $brokerId
     * @param int $sbCheckStatusId
     * @param int $statusVipId
     * @return array
     */
    public static function generate(int $brokerId, int $sbCheckStatusId, int $statusVipId): array
    {
        parent::init();

        return [
            'broker_id' => $brokerId, // ОШИБКА! Ключ должен быть 'broker' => ...
            'sb_check_status_id' => $sbCheckStatusId, // ОШИБКА! Ключ должен быть 'sb_check_status' => ...
            'status_vip_id' => $statusVipId, // ОШИБКА! Ключ должен быть 'status_vip' => ...
            'surname' => parent::$faker->regexify('[\d\w_-]{1,255}'),
            'name' => parent::$faker->regexify('[\d\w_-]{1,255}'),
            'middle_name' => parent::$faker->regexify('[\d\w_-]{1,255}'),
            'email' => parent::$faker->email,
            'phone' => parent::$faker->regexify('\+\d{1,4}\d{10}'),
            'birthday' => parent::$faker->date(),
            'created_at' => parent::$faker->dateTime(),
            'updated_at' => parent::$faker->dateTime(),
            'usdt_tether' => parent::$faker->regexify('[0-9a-f]{64}'),
            'active' => parent::$faker->randomElement(\App\Entity\PersonalArea::ACTIVE_LIST),
        ];
    }
}
```

Еще раз всех прошу прощения. Думаю этот позорный вопрос можно не удалять, на тот случай, если кто то допустит такую же ошибку и будет грешить на PHPUnit, который здесь вообще не виноват. Нужно было сразу копать в сторону валидаторов